# How can I get Eclipse to underline in red the imports which don't exist?

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently switched IDE's to Eclipse.
Just to test that I am not insane, I added something like

```
import x;
```

to the top of the Java file.  I was expecting to see the red squiggly line underlining the library the IDE can't find, but it didn't do it automatically.

How can I set the Eclipse setting to tell me if some syntax is wrong, or a library I am importing isn't in place?

Comment: Is the Java file located under a source folder? There isn't a setting for bad imports because that's a compiler error already.

Comment: and don't forget about Source->Organize Imports... which fixes all those problems quickly.

Comment: I get the error that "Source is not in the build path of the java project" - how is that usually fixed? I am able to invoke java or javac commands from command line so my paths seem to be set correctly.

Comment: @Genadinik: In typical Eclipse projects, source files need to be in the "src" folder. Beyond that (as with typical Java build practice) classes of a particular package need to be in a folder (inside src) that matches their package.

Comment: @Isaac: you should post an expanded version of that as an answer.

Comment: @jprete Late, since your answer got accepted, but I've added it.

Comment: @Isaac At least I can give you ten rep for the added value....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should flag it as a compiler error automatically (including the squiggly line). You might need to convince it to rebuild the project. Are you automatically building the project, or doing it manually? Eclipse occasionally loses track of automatic rebuilds.

Comment: How do I ask Eclipse to automatically rebuild?  I think that is what I need.

Comment: Actually that was simple.  I just chose the rebuild-automatically option lol. But it still isn't adding the squiggly lines. :(

Comment: That should help, but that's also where the "lose track of automatic rebuilds" part comes into play. It seems to sometimes forget to update the source view, the compiler error list, or both. Good odds that an Eclipse restart will help, although that's not a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unresolvable imports are a compiler error, not something you configure in Eclipse.

Make sure the file is located under a Java source directory:

`Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source tab`

Also verify that `Project > Build Automatically` is enabled. You may need to do a `Project > Clean` to jump start automatic builds.

Answer (score 1):

I can change mine in the following preferences.

```
Window->Preferences
General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations
Annotation types->Errors

Check the box: Text as
Select: Native Problem Underline as the drop down
Choose a color
```

Comment: Did that, but it is still not underlining the error.  I think it isn't set to try to find whats in the classpath.

Comment: Under Java->Editor. Do you have the "Report problems as you type" checked?